# Let $(A, \mathfrak{m})$ be a local ring. For a proper ideal $I$ of $A$, $\operatorname{ht} I = r$ implies that $\text{ht} (a_1, \dots, a_r) = r$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> Let $(A, \mathfrak{m})$ be a local ring. For a proper ideal $I$ of $A$, $\operatorname{ht} I = r$ implies that $\operatorname{ht} (a_1, \dots, a_r) = r$ for some $a_1, \dots, a_r \in I$.

I'm not sure why this is true. By definition, $\operatorname{ht} I = \text{inf}\{ \operatorname{ht} P \mid P \supseteq I\}$ so that it is equal to $\operatorname{ht} Q$ for some prime ideal $Q$. If $$Q \supseteq Q_1 \supseteq Q_2 \supseteq \cdots \supseteq Q_r$$ is a chain of the $Q_i$'s, then we may pick $a_1 \in (Q \cap I) - Q_1$, $a_2 \in (Q_1 \cap I) - Q_2$ and so on. However, we cannot assume that $Q_j$ contains any elements of $I$ for $j \geq 1$. Even if it did, maybe there is a shorter chain which contains those $r$ elements, right?

Comment: Induct on $r$, $r=0$ being trivial. Assume $r>0$. Then $I$ is not contained in any minimal primes say $P_1,\ldots P_n$, so pick $a_r\in I-\cup P_i$ and note that minimal primes are associated primes and go modulo $a_r$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let $A$ be a noetherian ring. For a proper ideal $I$ of $A$, $\operatorname{ht} I = r$ implies that there exist $a_1, \dots, a_r \in I$ such that $\operatorname{ht} (a_1, \dots, a_i) = i$ for $1\le i\le r$.

Suppose $r\ge 1$. Then $I\nsubseteq\bigcup_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Min}(A)}\mathfrak p$ and pick up $a_1\in I-\bigcup_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Min}(A)}\mathfrak p$. Then $\operatorname{ht}(a_1)=1$. If $r=1$ we are done.
Suppose $r\ge 2$. Then $I\nsubseteq\bigcup_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Min}((a_1))}\mathfrak p$ and pick up $a_2\in I-\bigcup_{\mathfrak p\in\operatorname{Min}((a_1))}\mathfrak p$. Then $\operatorname{ht}(a_1,a_2)=2$. If $r=2$ we are done.
And so on.